# How to get wrapped component instance with recompose?

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I'm using [`lifecycle`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle) to create a Higher-Ordered Component. I need access to the wrapped component instance. How can I get it?

e.g.

```
export default function ajaxLoader(options) {
    return lifecycle({
        componentWillMount() {
            // how to get *wrapped* component instance here?
            // `this` refers to an instance of the lifecycle HOC, not the wrapped component
            // i.e., I want the instance of `SomeComponent`
        }
    }) // this returns a function that accepts a component *class*
}
```

And the usage, if you want to see that too:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        return <span/>;
    }
}

const WrappedComponent = ajaxLoader({
    // options
})(SomeComponent);
```

I *think* I could have gotten a reference to the wrapped component if I overrode the `render()` method in my HOC, and rendered the wrapped component with `ref=...`, but `recompose` specifically won't let me implement the `render` method myself.

> It supports the entire Component API, except the render() method, which is implemented by default (and **overridden if specified; an error will be logged** to the console).

Comment: You can't get the wrapped component within `lifecycle`. What do you want to do with the wrapped component? I don't get the idea from your usage example.

Comment: @wuct Example wasn't meant to demonstrate a use-case, just structure. Suppose I want to call a custom method on the wrapped instance, how would I do that?

Comment: there is no way to access wrapped components or instances in `lifecycle`. You probably should lift those methods to a higher-order component or just use plain React.Component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must have access to instance methods you can do something like this:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.childController = null;
  }

  // access child method via this.childController.instanceMethod

  render() {
    return <DecoratedChildComponent provideController={controller => this.childController = controller} />
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.provideController({
      instanceMethod: this.instanceMethod,
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.provideController(null);
  }

  instanceMethod = () => {
    console.log("I'm the instance method");
  }
}
```

This is a little convoluted, and in most cases can be avoided, but it you really need to access an instance method, this will work

Comment: This work. after so long looking for this was the best solution thank you friend